# urlencode a multidimensional dictionary in python

Tags: python, urlencode

How can I get a URL-encoded version of a multidimensional dictionary in Python? Unfortunately, `urllib.urlencode()` only works in a single dimension. I would need a version capable of recursively encoding the dictionary.

For example, if I have the following dictionary:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': 'e'}}
```

I want to obtain the following string:

```
a=b&c[d]=e
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK people. I implemented it myself:

```
import urllib

def recursive_urlencode(d):
    """URL-encode a multidimensional dictionary.

    >>> data = {'a': 'b&c', 'd': {'e': {'f&g': 'h*i'}}, 'j': 'k'}
    >>> recursive_urlencode(data)
    u'a=b%26c&j=k&d[e][f%26g]=h%2Ai'
    """
    def recursion(d, base=[]):
        pairs = []

        for key, value in d.items():
            new_base = base + [key]
            if hasattr(value, 'values'):
                pairs += recursion(value, new_base)
            else:
                new_pair = None
                if len(new_base) > 1:
                    first = urllib.quote(new_base.pop(0))
                    rest = map(lambda x: urllib.quote(x), new_base)
                    new_pair = "%s[%s]=%s" % (first, ']['.join(rest), urllib.quote(unicode(value)))
                else:
                    new_pair = "%s=%s" % (urllib.quote(unicode(key)), urllib.quote(unicode(value)))
                pairs.append(new_pair)
        return pairs

    return '&'.join(recursion(d))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Still, I'd be interested to know if there's a better way to do this. I can't believe Python's standard library doesn't implement this.

Comment: Why should it? This is not in any way a standard format. The thing with the square brackets is a PHP-specific peculiarity not present in most other languages/frameworks or any web standard.

Comment: It may not be a pure-blood RFC-described IETF/W3C-backed holy-macaroni standard, but it's so commonly used nowadays that its not being included in Python's standard library does defy my comprehension.

I have developed web applications in a number of platforms and languages, and this has always been the convention. And this includes Python-based environments such as Django: so no, it's not a PHP-only thing anymore.

Comment: Just so people who come here later are aware, this code comes close to working but doesn't work for objects with > 1 nesting level.  So objects with > 1 nesting level get booted back to the top of the hash.

Comment: Eric Lubow: thanks for the bug report. I just corrected it and should be ok now.

Comment: Fantastic.  This saved me last night late.  Kind of sad that urllib/urllib2 and wrappers like requests don't natively support this.  Again, thank you - I wish I could upvote this 10 times.

Comment: Cpan has a module to handle this php encoding peculiarity; maybe the code will provide inspiration: https://github.com/mschilli/php-httpbuildquery-perl

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
a = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': 'e'}}

url = urllib.urlencode([('%s[%s]'%(k,v.keys()[0]), v.values()[0] ) if type(v)==dict else (k,v) for k,v in a.iteritems()])

url = 'a=b&c%5Bd%5D=e'
```

Comment: Afraid not. Please notice the difference between 'a=b&c[d]=e' and your proposed 'a=b&c%5Bd%5D=e'. That escaping should not be there.

Comment: Then you will have to iterate over the dictionary like I did and urlencode each item separately...

Comment: This only takes the first inner value in a dict but I like the way you did it so +1 for you hehe

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code of @malaney, I think that the code below emulates the PHP function `http_build_query()` quite well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.parse

def http_build_query(data):
    parents = list()
    pairs = dict()

    def renderKey(parents):
        depth, outStr = 0, ''
        for x in parents:
            s = "[%s]" if depth > 0 or isinstance(x, int) else "%s"
            outStr += s % str(x)
            depth += 1
        return outStr

    def r_urlencode(data):
        if isinstance(data, list) or isinstance(data, tuple):
            for i in range(len(data)):
                parents.append(i)
                r_urlencode(data[i])
                parents.pop()
        elif isinstance(data, dict):
            for key, value in data.items():
                parents.append(key)
                r_urlencode(value)
                parents.pop()
        else:
            pairs[renderKey(parents)] = str(data)

        return pairs
    return urllib.parse.urlencode(r_urlencode(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    payload = {
        'action': 'add',
        'controller': 'invoice',
        'code': 'debtor',
        'InvoiceLines': [
            {'PriceExcl': 150, 'Description': 'Setupfee'},
            {'PriceExcl':49.99, 'Description':'Subscription'}
        ],
        'date': '2016-08-01',
        'key': 'Yikes&ampersand'
    }
    print(http_build_query(payload))

    payload2 = [
        'item1',
        'item2'
    ]
    print(http_build_query(payload2))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the code below may be what you want

```
import urllib.parse

def url_encoder(params):
    g_encode_params = {}

    def _encode_params(params, p_key=None):
        encode_params = {}
        if isinstance(params, dict):
            for key in params:
                encode_key = '{}[{}]'.format(p_key,key)
                encode_params[encode_key] = params[key]
        elif isinstance(params, (list, tuple)):
            for offset,value in enumerate(params):
                encode_key = '{}[{}]'.format(p_key, offset)
                encode_params[encode_key] = value
        else:
            g_encode_params[p_key] = params

        for key in encode_params:
            value = encode_params[key]
            _encode_params(value, key)

    if isinstance(params, dict):
        for key in params:
            _encode_params(params[key], key)

    return urllib.parse.urlencode(g_encode_params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = {'name': 'interface_name', 'interfaces': [{'interface': 'inter1'}, {'interface': 'inter2'}]}
    print(url_encoder(params))
```

the output is

```
interfaces%5B1%5D%5Binterface%5D=inter2&name=interface_name&interfaces%5B0%5D%5Binterface%5D=inter1
```

which is look like

```
interfaces[1][interface]=inter2&name=interface_name&interfaces[0][interface]=inter1
```

PS: you may want use `OrderDict` to replace `dict` above

Answer (score 2):

The above solution only works for arrays with depth < 2.  The code below will properly urlencode a multidimensional array of any depth.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import urllib

def recursive_urlencode(data):
    def r_urlencode(data, parent=None, pairs=None):
        if pairs is None:
            pairs = {}
        if parent is None:
            parents = []
        else:
            parents = parent

        for key, value in data.items():
            if hasattr(value, 'values'):
                parents.append(key)
                r_urlencode(value, parents, pairs)
                parents.pop()
            else:
                pairs[renderKey(parents + [key])] = renderVal(value)

        return pairs
    return urllib.urlencode(r_urlencode(data))


def renderKey(parents):
    depth, outStr = 0, ''
    for x in parents:
        str = "[%s]" if depth > 0 else "%s"
        outStr += str % renderVal(x)
        depth += 1
    return outStr


def renderVal(val):
    return urllib.quote(unicode(val))


def main():
    print recursive_urlencode(payload)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: This function seems to pass the string through unicode twice.  So a '!' turns into '%25%21' not simply '%21'

Answer (score 1):

The function get_encoded_url_params() takes a dict as argument and returns url encoded form of the dict.

```
def get_encoded_url_params(d):
    """URL-encode a nested dictionary.
    :param d = dict
    :returns url encoded string with dict key-value pairs as query parameters
    e.g.
    if d = { "addr":{ "country": "US", "line": ["a","b"] },
            "routing_number": "011100915", "token": "asdf"
        }
    :returns 'addr[country]=US&addr[line][0]=a&addr[line][1]=b&routing_number=011100915&token=asdf'
    or 'addr%5Bcountry%5D=US&addr%5Bline%5D%5B0%5D=a&addr%5Bline%5D%5B1%5D=b&routing_number=011100915&token=asdf'
    (which is url encoded form of the former using quote_plus())
    """

    def get_pairs(value, base):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return get_dict_pairs(value, base)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            return get_list_pairs(value, base)
        else:
            return [base + '=' + str(value)]
            # use quote_plus() to get url encoded string
            # return [quote_plus(base) + '=' + quote_plus(str(value))]

    def get_list_pairs(li, base):
        pairs = []
        for idx, value in enumerate(li):
            new_base = base + '[' + str(idx) + ']'
            pairs += get_pairs(value, new_base)
        return pairs

    def get_dict_pairs(d, base=''):
        pairs = []
        for key, value in d.items():
            new_base = key if base == '' else base + '[' + key + ']'
            pairs += get_pairs(value, new_base)
        return pairs

    return '&'.join(get_dict_pairs(d))
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart the function get_encoded_url_params() takes a dict/map and gives key-value pairs as url encoded parameters. It's similar to urllib.urlencode() but also works the case when there is dict or list inside the original dict. I have provided an example in the comment inside function.

Answer (score 0):

what about json.dumps and json.loads?

```
d = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': 'e'}}
s = json.dumps(d)  # s: '{"a": "b", "c": {"d": "e"}}'
json.loads(s)  # -> d
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but seems to me that json.dumps followed by a url-encode does seem like a great solution to the problem. This particular construction of query strings across frameworks (like Django etc.) evolved with the widespread use of json, so the string representation being valid json is not a mere accident. json.dumps (which is recursion-aware) is thus the more Pythonic solution. The URL-encoding at the end is incidental to the problem, and should be the responsibility of a library that keeps up with encoding standards, so once again the solution is best left to urllib.

Answer (score 0):

what about this simplified version:

```
def _clean(value):
    return urllib.quote(unicode(value))

'&'.join([ v for val in [[ "%s[%s]=%s"%(k,ik, _(iv)) 
    for ik, iv in v.items()] if type(v)==dict else ["%s=%s"%(k,_(v))] 
    for k,v in data.items() ] 
    for v in val ])
```

I agree is not readable, maybe flattening the list can be better done with itertools.chain instead of another list comprehension.

This only goes 1 level deeper, yours can go N levels deeper if you would add some logic to manage N numbers of "[%s]" depending on the level, but I guess is not that necesary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert python dict/list/nested to PHP Array like urlencoded string.

In python, most of the data type you want to convert to urlencoded maybe: `dict` `list` `tuple` `nested of them`, Like

```
a = [1, 2]
print(recursive_urlencode(a))
# 0=1&1=2


a2 = (1, '2')
print(recursive_urlencode(a2))
# 0=1&1=2


b = {'a': 11, 'b': 'foo'}
print(recursive_urlencode(b))
# a=11&b=foo


c = {'a': 11, 'b': [1, 2]}
print(recursive_urlencode(c))
# a=11&b[0]=1&b[1]=2


d = [1, {'a': 11, 'b': 22}]
print(recursive_urlencode(d))
# 0=1&1[a]=11&1[b]=22


e = {'a': 11, 'b': [1, {'c': 123}, [3, 'foo']]}
print(recursive_urlencode(e))
# a=11&b[0]=1&b[1][c]=123&b[2][0]=3&b[2][1]=foo
```

https://github.com/Viky-zhang/to_php_post_arr

P.S. some code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4014164/2752670