# Invalid data format returned from httplib.HTTPSConnection request

Tags: python, json, api, response, httplib

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import httplib, urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({"username":"api", "password":"cisco123", "data":{"token":""}})
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Accept":"application/json"}

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("10.86.79.93", 443)
conn.request("GET", "/restapi/16/authenticate", params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()

print "\n"

print response.status, response.reason

data = response.read()

print "\n"

print data

print "\n"

print response.msg

print "\n”

Output:

The response data is looking for JSON and here is the example they give:


“data”:{“token”:”1234567890xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”}

200 OK


{"status":100,"message":"Invalid data format.","data":null,"envelope_version":"16"}
```

- Date: Fri, 15 Aug 2014 00:10:49 GMT
- Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
- X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.14
- Content-Length: 83
- Connection: close
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Any idea why I would be getting "Invalid data format” message and null in the data response?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that urllib.urlencode doesn't handle nested json well. You have a nested object in "data":{"token":""}. Look at [urlencode a multidimensional dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013838/urlencode-a-multidimensional-dictionary-in-python)
for a solution.