# Zurmo: Python request - data format

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to push some data into Zurmo CRM using a python script but I am getting problems with the data format. For the http request I am using the ***requests*** module from Python.

Below I share with you a piece of my code with the data and the HTTP request, respectively:

**Data**:

```
data = {
    "firstName": "Python",
    "lastName": "IAmNotBlank",
    "officePhone": "01254870016",
    "companyName": "Python Test",
    "state": {
        "id": str(1)
    },
    "owner": {
        "id": str(6)
    },
    "source": {
        "value": "Website Form"
    },
    "primaryEmail": "luis@eazycollect.co.uk",
    "sunCstm": {
        "value": "I have my own SUN"
    },
    "averageCstm": "100",
    "oftenCstm": {
        "value": "Weekly"
    },
    "ddcustCstm": "100",
    "website": "www.google.com"
}
```

**HTTP request:**

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "ZURMO_API_REQUEST_TYPE": "REST",
    "ZURMO_SESSION_ID": tokens["sessionID"],
    "ZURMO_TOKEN": tokens["token"]
}

r = requests.post(url=zURL+zInstance, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I can also share with you a reply from a Zurmo's developer:

> The reason for error is because data that you send to api should be dictionary with "data" element and that is what I am sure based on error, so I think you should change your code to something like this: 
>   data = urllib.urlencode({"data" => zurmo_data}) 
>   which should be equivalent like PHP code: 
>   $response = ApiRestHelper::createApiCall('http://example.com/index.php/contacts/contact/api/create/';, 'POST', $headers, array('data' => $data));

In my code the **requests.post()** method is already encoding the data, it does the same job as the *urllib.urlencode()* by default. If you want you can have a look on Zurmo API in this link: http://zurmo.org/wiki/rest-api-specification-contacts. They use PHP as an example.

Finally i share with you the server response upon my request:

```
200 
{"status":"FAILURE","data":null,"message":"Please provide data.","errors":null}
```

Has someone experienced the same?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me how Zurmo expects the data to be encoded; if they want URL-encoded data, you'll need to do more work on the keys still as PHP has their own proprietary way of encoding that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a *top-level dictionary* with a `'data'` key:

```
data = {'data': data}
```

This is what the developer meant by their remark; in all PHP samples they give they wrap the entire `data` dictionary in such an outer dictionary with a `'data'` key.

If the Zurmo API expects you to URL-encode this, you'll have to manually do so to implement the PHP-style keys for that. See [urlencode a multidimensional dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013838/urlencode-a-multidimensional-dictionary-in-python).

You could use the [`multidimensional_urlencode` package](https://github.com/uber/multidimensional_urlencode) here to accomplish that:

```
from multidimensional_urlencode import urlencode

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "ZURMO_API_REQUEST_TYPE": "REST",
    "ZURMO_SESSION_ID": tokens["sessionID"],
    "ZURMO_TOKEN": tokens["token"],
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}
post_body = urlencode(data)
r = requests.post(url=zURL+zInstance, data=post_body, headers=headers)
```

Because you are encoding the POST body yourself, you need to manually set the Content-Type header.

Comment: Changed to a top-level dictionary with a 'data' key and now i got server error "500" with this message: An error has occurred. Please click <a href="https://eazycollect.zurmocloud.com/crm/app/index.php">here</a> to continue to the home page. If the error persists please contact your administrator. **Argument 2 passed to ZurmoModuleApiController::setModelScenarioFromData() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/eazycoll/public_html/crm/app/protected/modules/zurmo/components/ZurmoModuleApiController.php on line 619 and defined.**

Comment: @LuísSardinha: see the remarks about passing in a multidimensional dictionary here. PHP (and Ruby-on-Rails) use an extension to the standard form-encoded parameters format used by browsers to add structure, which is automatically parsed back out to PHP arrays (the equivalent of a Python dict).

Comment: @LuísSardinha: so you are now 1) wrapping your original dictionary in another one with the `'data'` key, and 2) sending the post body encoded as a multidimensional encoding? Can you show us the actual post body produced?

Comment: Wait Martijn, it is good. Sorry but i wasn't encoding the top-level dictionary but still the original data dictionary. It worked!! Thank you very much mate.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been fighting this API for the last 2 hours. Most of it was clear to me (I even ended up finding that same package directly), but I was missing the content-type header.